# How to send a Base64 encoded PDF from a Mironaut controller?

Tags: micronaut

I would like to send a Base64 encoded PDF string to a clients (such as a browser). How do I have to declare my controller action in order a browser can display the Base64 encoded PDF? Here is what I did so far.

```java
@Get(value = "/downloadDocument", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM )
public String downloadDocument() throws IOException {
    byte[] fileAsBytes =  calledExternalService();
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileAsBytes);
}
```

Comment: if the answer below works for you, please let others know by accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Tell your client that the response is a PDF but base64 encoded. You can achieve this by changing the value of `@Produces` within your controller

```java
@Produces("application/pdf;base64")
```